# use of orWhere() in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a eloquent query that I am running twice, but feel can be run once.

I'd want to return the values of the first where statement if exists otherwise check the second where statement which is the default in the query.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
$details = Telco::select('telcos.id AS telco_id', 'telcos.name AS telco_name')
         ->leftJoin('telco_prefixs', 'telco_prefixs.telco_id', '=', 'telcos.id')
         ->where('telco_prefixs.prefix', '=',  $phone_number) // check if ndc exists
         ->first();


if ($details){

    return $details;
}

    return Telco::select('telcos.id AS telco_id', 'telcos.name AS telco_name')
         ->leftJoin('telco_prefixs', 'telco_prefixs.telco_id', '=', 'telcos.id')
         ->where('telcos.name', '=', 'Default') //default channel
         ->first();
```

I have a feeling this can be combined to something like below:

However, this fails as keeps executing the OrWhere clause.

```
Telco::select('telcos.id AS telco_id', 'telcos.name AS telco_name')
     ->leftJoin('telco_prefixs', 'telco_prefixs.telco_id', '=', 'telcos.id')
     ->where('telco_prefixs.prefix', '=', $phone_number)    // if ndc exists
     ->Orwhere('telcos.name', '=', 'Default')    //default channel
     ->first();
```

Someone help. Thanks

Comment: yes there is already orWhere (small o letter W capital ) https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: Can you share the two table structure and whether the `leftJoin` is necessary (and why)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your where and or where condition as below.

```
Telco::select('telcos.id AS telco_id', 'telcos.name AS telco_name')
     ->leftJoin('telco_prefixs', 'telco_prefixs.telco_id', '=', 'telcos.id')
     ->where(function ($query) use($phone_number) {
          $query->where('telco_prefixs.prefix', '=', $phone_number);
          $query->Orwhere('telcos.name', '=', 'Default');
     })->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to use just eloquent a possible solution would be to have something like:

I suppose you have model called Telco and another one calle TelcoPrefix.

```php
//Telco.php
//first we create a has many relationship with your telco_prefixs table.
public function telcoPrefixs(){
    return $this->hasMany(TelcoPrefix::class);
}
```

Once you have that relationship you can use something similar to this code:

```php
Telco::whereHas('telcoPrefixs',function($query, $phone_number){
  return $query->where('prefix,'=',$phone_number);
})->select('id','name')->first();
```

This will compare the relationship and if it exists or has it will return your first record in one query.

Hope it helps at least to give a guide of what you can do.